# Frankfurt hotel near airport

Tags: transit, hotels, frankfurt

I am landing at Frankfurt late at 10+ pm. Thinking to rest for a night before continue the land transit to destination. Any idea what is the value for money hotel that I could stay for a  short night? Of course with all my luggages.

Comment: Traveling alone

Comment: https://www.parkinn.com/airporthotel-frankfurt

Comment: FRA or HHN?  The answer could be much different.

Answer (score 4):

There's [a Hilton Garden Inn directly connected to the airport](http://www3.hilton.com/en/hotels/hesse/hilton-frankfurt-airport-FRAHAHI/index.html) (FRA, let us know if you're going to HHN), which you could consider.

It's also [a 12 minute trip by train](https://www.frommers.com/destinations/frankfurt/planning-a-trip/getting-there) from FRA to the city's main train station, which has connections all over the city, so you could use any hotel booking site to find a hotel in the city near public transit that meets your personal definition of "value for money." You could also give thought to where your land transit leaves from.

Comment: +1 for taking a train to the city (although he should probably plan for something like 30 minutes arrivals-to-Fra Hbf)

Comment: Trains go every 15 minutes (platform 1), until midnight. After midnight there are still trains, but the schedule is changing frequently due to construction works.

Answer (score 2):

Hilton and Sheraton are right in the airport. There are cheaper offsite locations very close by, but you will need to use their shuttle. For example for a midweek night next week, you'd pay around $130 for Sheraton or Hilton and offsite locations could be less than $80 (Ibis, Moxy, Park Inn Radisson)

If you go offsite, I would recommend contacting the hotel up front about shuttle instructions (pick up point, schedule, number to call, etc.). The airport is huge and fairly convoluted.

Stating the obvious: Typing "Frankfurt Airport Hotels" into Google will give a great overview of choices, prices and locations for any given date.